# Flutter restart and reload issue

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey friends I am facing an issue when I restart my app then I am not able to click on any button on screen. Whenever I hot reload it then I am able to click. I am using Getx package in flutter.

Comment: Try setting up emulator again using Device Manager, and clear android studio cache

Comment: Are there any error logs?

Comment: no there is no error log

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using android emulator, right? Sometimes this happens to me, just click on the bezel of the emulator device until the screen is brighter (the difference is very small, you should pay attention to it). Then try to click on device screen again. If this still doesn't work, stop you device then try to start the emulator using cold boot, see [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#common) or you just simply choose cold boot option if you using vscode to start your emulator.

[image: like on this picture]